# Вопрос про область видимости, замыкания

Tags: javascript

Немного непонятно с данным кодом - почему внутри квадратов выводится цифра 5, а не последовательные 0..4?

Есть версия:
- цикл прогоняется намного быстрее, и пока выполнится первый setTimeout, счетчик уже достиг максимального значения.

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.rows').append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
    }, 800 * i);
    $('.res').text($('.res').text() + " " + i);
  }
});
```

```css
.rows > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3c3;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вызов `setTimeout` Не останавливает выполнения, а просто планирует вызов функции цикл выполняется сразу весь.
Таким образом на последней итерации:

значение `i` = 4.
вызывается `i++`, значение уже 5
проверка условий цикла `i < 5`
выход из цикла.

Таким образом после окончания цикла значение переменной равно 5.

Следом начинают выполняться функции запланированные с помощью `setTimeout`

```
function() {
  $('.rows').append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
}
```

Так как значение `i` - 5, то и выводится `5`.

> цикл прогоняется намного быстрее, и пока выполнится первый setTimeout

Неверная догадка. Так как яваскрипт выполняется в одном потоке, выполнение функции не может прерываться. То есть, независимо от значения интервала указанного в таймауте сначала выполнится весь цикл и оставшаяся часть функции и лишь затем, если в очереди ничего нет, будет выполнена отложенная функция.

Comment: Да-да, с последней итерацией сразу же после задания вопроса разобрался.

Comment: А если for() внутри for()? Первый прерывается или нет пока выполнится вложенный for()?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, выполнение строго последовательно. Обыкновенная однопоточная программа.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, кстати, не совсем понял как первый for может прерваться, если вложенный выполняется **внутри** него

Comment: да так, из ответа выбрал слова) а какие еще есть функции, планирующие вызов функций?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, `setInterval`: [WindowTimers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers)