# Анимированное заполнение таблицы

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Есть функция, которая заполняет ячейки элементами массива:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

(function addInCell() {
    var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i <= cell.length; i++) {
       cell[i].value = arr[i];
    }
})();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить заполнение ячеек не сразу, а пошагово - 1, задержка, 2, задержка и т.д.?
Т.е., как бы анимированное заполнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  (function addInCell() {
    var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
      var s = function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          cell[i].value = arr[i];
        }, 1000 * i)
      }
      s(i);
    }
  })();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
```

Comment: Как то много лишнего, + переприсвоение непонятной переменной s? Сделай замыкание и все

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев и как именно замыкание?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев вы про это? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506556/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F