# Открытие страницы с заполненными полями

Tags: javascript

Добрый день
Есть скрипт 
По клику на поле скрипт открывает новое окно с определенной страницей авторизации
Нужно чтобы при открытии этой страницы автоматически заполнялись поля логин и пароль
Скрипт в битрикс 24 (onclick)
Сейчас там только window.open('https://lk.platon.ru/sign_in?locale=ru/');
Необходимо чтобы  поля логин и пароль были заполнены , авторизовываться на автомате не обязательно
Кто-нибудь может помочь в таком вопросе?

Comment: Что если сохранять данные в куки и считывать их при открытии страницы? https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: куки старо как мир, есть localStorage

Comment: @Василий Барбашев Я о нем узнал только 2 недели назад, еще ничего не пробовал, так что не советую неопознанное :)

Comment: @Levelleor это лучше чем куки, + нормальное API для работы. Без самописных функций для кук

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны понимать, что это не совсем безопасно, автозаполнять логин и пароль. Чтобы их заполнить, необходимо отдать сервером клиенту, а чтобы отдать безопасно, надо клиента идентифицировать наверняка, чтобы данные не угнали мерзавцы), можно конечно, что-то придумать, сохранить в localStorage или еще что-то типа хеша в куки, но тогда придется все равно один раз вводить их самому (я не специалист по безопасности).

Кстати примерчик localStorage, основанный на этом [Анимированное заполнение таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508278/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/508286#508286)

Пример на [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hicadateka/edit?html,js,output) работает.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  if (localStorage.myItem == null) {
    localStorage.myItem = JSON.stringify(arr);
    alert('хранилище пока не заполнено');
  }

  var val = JSON.parse(localStorage.myItem);

  (function addInCell() {
    var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          cell[i].value = val[i];
        }, 500 * i)
      })(i);
    }
  })();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<input type="text" name="" id="">
```